# Ubuntu Networking Guide

Tags: networking

Please can someone give me a link to help me understand the following things:

1. The syntax of the man pages. When I do a man ifconfig, I am struggling to work out which parts of the cli are compsulary, which are optional, which are variable etc. I need some guidance on working these things out so I can actually use the man page to work out the commands.
2. I need to understand how to check the layer1 network connectivity from the CLI. For example, on a Cisco switch, I can do a #sh int [interface name], and I will be able to see that the interface is up and has negotiated to full duplex and 100 Mb. I'm pretty sure I was on the terminal of my Ubuntu machine last night and it was showing interfaces as up, even without a cable connected. So how do you work out if layer 1 conectivity is working on Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you even google "Ubuntu Networking Guide"?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Please only ask one question at a time. A helpful person might know one answer, but hesitate to reply due to not knowing the other.  *I wanted this to be item 0, to match the question*
2. Read `man man`, which says, in part:

   ```
   A manual page consists of several sections.

   Conventional  section names include NAME, SYNOPSIS, CONFIGURATION, DESCRIPTION, OPTIONS, EXIT STATUS, RETURN VALUE, ERRORS, ENVIRONMENT, FILES, VERSIONS, CONFORMING TO, NOTES, BUGS, EXAMPLE, AUTHORS, and SEE ALSO.  

   The following conventions apply to the SYNOPSIS section and can be used as a guide in other sections.

   bold text          type exactly as shown.
   italic text        replace with appropriate argument.
   [-abc]             any or all arguments within [ ] are optional.
   -a|-b              options delimited by | cannot be used together.
   argument ...       argument is repeatable.
   [expression] ...   entire expression within [ ] is repeatable.

   Exact rendering may vary depending on the output device.  For instance, man will usually not be able to render italics when running in a terminal, and will  typically  use  underlined  or coloured text instead.
   ```
3. To see if your system thinks that it has working network interfaces: `ifconfig -a`, check for `UP`, `inet addr:` and `inet6 addr:` reasonable values; to see a few more values, `sudo ifconfig -a`

To see if your system knows where to send packets, `ip route` and ensure that the `default via` route exists and mentions the IP address of the "right" interface from `ifconfig -a`;

To see all of the systems on the same Ethernet link as your system: `arp -an`. You should see at least the IP address of the `default` route, and may see other IPs.;

For other networking information (stats, counts, etc), see `man 5 proc` (the `/proc/net` part, and `man netstat`.